# Using lock_guard in loop

Tags: c++, stl, mutex

I have an array where each of its entries is a linked list. To avoid synchronization problems when accessing the linked lists I added a mutex to each entry.

My question is can I convert the following calls to `lock` and `unlock` in each iteration of the loop to one `lock_guard` as shown below? Will the mutex of each entry be unlocked after each iteration? Thanks.

```
for(int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
{
    table[i].entryMtx.lock ();

    //... access the linked list of the entry...

    table[i].entryMtx.unlock ();
}

// --->

for(int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
{
    std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk (table[i].entryMtx);

    // ... access the linked list of the entry
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Yes, you can.

Comment: [`When a lock_guard object is created, it attempts to take ownership of the mutex it is given. When control leaves the scope in which the lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the mutex is released.`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is how destructors are used in C++ (and other languages).

However, it's not `stdx`, it's `std`. Probably a typo.